# Java Regex not finding all results

Tags: java, regex, java-8

Using Java 8, I have the following snippets of code:

Here:

```
private ArrayList<MatchResult> allMatches(final Pattern p, final CharSequence input){
    ArrayList<MatchResult> results = new ArrayList<MatchResult>();
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
    while(matcher.find()){
        results.add(matcher.toMatchResult());
    }
    return results;
}
```

And the main method here:

```
List<MatchResult> matches = allMatches(Pattern.compile(searchString),    searchable.getText());
System.out.println(matches.size());
```

The searchString variable holds the following String:

```
(?im)Exception
```

The **searchable's** text is this:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
```

As you can see, there are 3 times in the **searchable's** text where we see the word "exception". However, Java is only finding 2 of them.

The output of the code is this:

```
2
```

One more piece of information about this, is that the **searchString** variable comes from the user.

My question is regarding the number of matches. Java seems to be missing some matches when using regex. The text I provided comes from a bigger file, and this isn't the first one it's missed, but it is the one I'm focusing on to hopefully have some hint of where to look. What is going on here? Why is Java missing some matches? Is there a more accurate regular expression search that I should use?

To hopefully help those that aren't familiar with the "(?im)" in the **searchString** variable, I've located a resource [here](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-2/#section-7).

Comment: It outputs 3 for me. Try posting a more complete code excerpt, instead of fragments?

Comment: use `matcher.group()`

Comment: It might be safer to specify the flags using the two-argument version of Pattern.compile. Also, user input should be passed through Pattern.quote(). - Impossible to tell why this should only return 2.

Comment: Question is not *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable*. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. --- *Verifiable* is easy to do by writing a small test snippet by initializing `searchString` and changing `searchable.getText()` to `searchText` and initializing it. That also takes care of *Minimal* and *Complete*. And would make you not post the question, since the code returns 3.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone it helped point me in the right direction. Also, @Andreas thanks for pointing me to that resource for future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it was not in the code I posted, as that is proprietary code and cannot be put out in public domain. But basically the **searchString** was not being sent to the Pattern compiler correctly and the "(?im)" was stripped off before arrival. Thank you all for your help.